How do I understand string arrays conversions in Assembly
There is a register that contains a string. I do not understand the implicit conversions that is happening when the following instructions are done.
##The following commands are all done in gdb
Set $r12="CS21"
print *$r12 -> 825381699
Set $r12="C"
print *$r12 -> 67 #ascii value of C,ok there is a clue here 
Set $r12 = "CS" 
print *$r12 -> 21315 #now I am not so sure

I tried some interpretations like "CS" = 0x6783, "CS" = 0x4353 to convert them to integer but I am unable to get the value above. How does the conversion happen?

That doesn't look like any assembly I've seen before. Or C for that matter. Please [edit] your question to give more details. And make sure the tags are matching the question.

FYI, strings are a variable length data type, and so we typically work with strings stored in memory, by using a pointer (to the beginng) and often, when working with them, typically look at only one byte at a time, one byte after another (rather than, say, looking at 2, 3, or 4 bytes at once).

In this case, a string is convert into bytes and these bytes are combined into an integer according to little-endian order.
For first one, we got a string CS21. It will stored in register like this:
Bytes order     3   2   1   0
Char            1   2   S   C
ASCII in hex    31  32  53  43

So we get an hexadecimal integer 0x31325343, which is 825381699 in Decimal.
For third one, We got a string "CS". Similarly, it will stored in register like this:
Bytes order     3   2   1   0
Char                    S   C
ASCII in hex            53  43

So we get an hexadecimal integer 0x5343, which is 21315 in Decimal.
For interpretations in the question:

0x6783 is obviously inappropriate. 67 and 83 are decimal ASCII of C and S and they should not be put together as hexadecimal.
0x4353 is really close to the correct interpretation. But little-endian order are used in this case, which means the first char should be placed at the lowest position.

